# INSERT RLS policy not working with 2 simple tables

Tags: supabase

INSERT policy was created in tags table using Supabase UI:
`(picture_id IN ( SELECT pictures.id FROM pictures WHERE (pictures.owner = auth.uid())))`
[image: screenshot]

pictures table:
id: uuid
created_at: timestamptz
owner: uuid FK auth.users.id
url: text

tags table:
id: uuid
created_at: timestamptz
picture_id: uuid FK pictures.id
tag: uuid FK auth.users.id

Client side code should insert data successfully but it quietly fails (no error, as expected when RLS policy is not satisfied in Supabase)

```js
const data = await supabase.from("tags").insert({ picture_id: uuid, tag: session?.user.id });
```

If I change policy to "true" in the UI it works so it's not an API problem.

Comment: Please describe in what way is RLS not working.

Comment: I try to do an INSERT satisfying the policy, specifically pictures.owner = auth.uid() but it doesn't insert. I don't know how to go about debugging this. I tried to run a similar query manually in Supabase SQL tab and it works, query I tried:  select * from tags where (picture_id IN ( SELECT pictures.id FROM pictures WHERE (pictures.owner = 'hard_coded_uuid')))

Comment: We would need the client side code you are using, and can you share the entire insert RLS policy that you have set on your table that you are trying to perform insert on to see fully what is going on. Could you share them?

Comment: Client code:  `const data = await supabase.from("tags").insert({
      picture_id: uuid,
      tag: session?.user.id,
    });`  policy in tags table `BEGIN;
  ALTER POLICY "only owners can add tags" ON "public"."tags" WITH CHECK ((picture_id IN ( SELECT pictures.id FROM pictures WHERE (pictures.owner = auth.uid()))));
COMMIT;`   thank you

Comment: Instead of writing them on the comments, could you edit your question and add them there? Also, the policy you have shared seems like a edited version. Could you also share the original SQL statement that created the policy?

Comment: Updated the question with your questions, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you already have a row in the `pictures` table where the id matches the `picture_id` that you are trying to perform insert on? Also, Supabase does return an error for insert when RLS policy fails. You can see the get the returned error like this: `const { error } = await supabase.from('table').insert(data)`. Could you verify that you are getting a RLS error?